# Passing array elements to varargs

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I have the following method on a superclass:

```
public void method(Example... examples) {
        for (Example e : examples) {
            e.doSomething();
        }
    }
```

And this is the call on the subclass:

```
super.method(examples[0], examples[1], examples[2], examples[3], examples[4], examples[5], examples[6], examples[7], examples[8], examples[9], examples[10]);
```

Is there an easier way to pass the elements? Something like super.method(examples[0 -> 10]) ?

I can't pass the entire array (super.method(examples)) to the method.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you pass the whole array? Is it too long?

Comment: Why don't you try 2d array in this even you don't need varargs .and also as far i know there is no such way to pass data.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I use the super method to align cells of a table. Sometimes I need to align cells 1->3 and 8 left and 4->7 and 9->11 right.

Comment: Why not `public void method(Example[] examples, int start, int end)`? Not every method processing an array benefits from declaring it as varargs.

Comment: OK, well then the copyOfRange solution will work for you.

Comment: @Holger Yes, Elliot has suggested that in the comments of his answer below. That makes it better indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage [`Arrays.copyOfRange(T[], int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) method

```
super.method(Arrays.copyOfRange(examples, 1, 11));
```

An example is below.

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestVarArgs {

    public void test(String...strings){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestVarArgs().test(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, 11));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) like

```
super.method(Arrays.copyOf(examples, 11));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the beginning of the array might not be [0], so I needed a way to set it. Sanj's answer has it. Your answer answers the question too, thought. Thank you.

Comment: @DiogoGarcia It might be better (more efficient anyway) to pass the start and end indexes to your method (along with the entire array).

Comment: Awesome. That makes it even cleaner on the subclass. Thank you!