# How to pass elements of ArrayList Of Pair into a vararg

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have this function

```
private fun gotoDestinationMain(id: Int, bundle: Bundle?, sharedView: ArrayList<Pair<View, String>>?) {

        var extras: FragmentNavigator.Extras? = null

        if (id == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not implemented yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        if (sharedView != null) {
            extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras()
        }

        findNavController().navigate(id, bundle, null, extras)
    }
```

The function `FragmentNavigatorExtras()` accepts `vararg sharedElements: Pair<View, String>`.

So how can I pass elements of `ArrayList` into the function?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36440996/7436566) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using spread operator:

```
val typedArray: Array<Pair<View, String>> = sharedView.toTypedArray()
FragmentNavigatorExtras(*typedArray)
```

documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs